# QMLのUi上にWidgetで作成したUiを取り込む方法

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator

お世話になります。Kaedeです。
Widgetで作成したUiが既にあるのですが、それをQMLのUi上に取り込むことって可能でしょうか？
(Widget上にQMLを取り込む時に使う「QQuickWidget」の逆のようなものや、それに近い動作を実現する方法があればご教授頂きたいです。)

Qt初心者ですので、考え方やクラス、参考リンクなどだけでもご教授いただければ幸いです。

【使用環境】

- Qt Creator 4.5.1 (Community)
- Qt 5.10.1
- Qt Quick 2.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

机上知識の回答になりますが、C++で記述したWidgetをQt Quickで利用するには、`QQmlExtensionPlugin`でラップしてQMLの型として登録する必要があると思います。詳しくは以下を参照してみてください。

[Writing QML Extensions with C++ : Chapter 6: Writing an Extension Plugin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-qml-example.html#chapter-6-writing-an-extension-plugin)

参考になれば幸いです。