# QtのQML拡張プラグイン使用でアプリがクラッシュしてしまう

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

こんにちは、Kaedeです。
以前、質問した「[qmlのui上にwidgetで作成したuiを取り込む方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/57194/qml%E3%81%AEui%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%ABwidget%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E3%81%97%E3%81%9Fui%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E3%82%8A%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)」の回答をもとに、`Widget(ui)`を`QML拡張プラグイン`として登録し、別プロジェクトの`SwipeView`に配置してみました。

しかし、ビルドは通るものの、実行をすると以下ダイアログが表示された後「再試行」でクラッシュしてしまいます。

[image: エラーダイアログ]

エラーメッセージは以下の通りです。(一部..に置き換えています。)

```
Starting C:\..\Qt_Project\swipeTestPrj\swipeTestPrj\..build\debug\swipeTestPrj.exe...
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
ASSERT: "!d->isWidget" in file kernel\qobject.cpp, line 1979
プログラムが突然終了しました。
The process was ended forcefully.
C:/../Qt_Project/swipeTestPrj/swipeTestPrj/..build/debug/swipeTestPrj.exe crashed.
```

【環境】
・Qt Creator 4.5.1 (Community)
・Qt 5.10.1
・Qt Quick 2.9
・windows 10 Pro , MSVC++ Compiler 15.8

このエラーを解決する方法について、ご存知の方がいればご教授頂きたいです。

---

[19/08/21追記]
以下ファイル構成とソースコードです。

**ファイル構成**
[image: ファイル構成]

**swipeTestPrj.pro**

```
include(../QmlInWidgetElement/qmlinwidgetelement.pri) #追記

QT += quick widgets
CONFIG += c++11
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**qmlinwidgetelement.pri**

```
QT += quick widgets
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD

# Input
SOURCES += $$PWD/mywidgetitem.cpp
HEADERS += $$PWD/mywidgetitem.h
FORMS += $$PWD/mywidgetitem.ui
DISTFILES += $$PWD/qmldir
```

**mywidgetitem.h**

```
#ifndef MYWIDGETITEM_H
#define MYWIDGETITEM_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class MyWidgetItem;
}

class MyWidgetItem : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyWidgetItem(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MyWidgetItem();

private:
    Ui::MyWidgetItem *ui;
};

#endif // MYWIDGETITEM_H
```

**mywidgetitem.cpp**

```
#include "mywidgetitem.h"
#include "ui_mywidgetitem.h"

MyWidgetItem::MyWidgetItem(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyWidgetItem)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MyWidgetItem::~MyWidgetItem()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
// Add
#include <mywidgetitem.h>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Add-
    qmlRegisterType<MyWidgetItem>("WidgetElements", 1, 0, "MyWidgetItem");
    // ----

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;


    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import WidgetElements 1.0 // Add

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Tabs")

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent

        Page1Form {
        }

        Page2Form {
        }
        // Add-
        MyWidgetItem{
            /* ここにWidgetを使って作成した画面を表示したい */
        }
        // ----
    }

}
```

**mywidgetitem.h**
　・Buttonをいくつか適当に配置する

**~ui.qml**
　・Labelをいくつか適当に配置する

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QMLの中にQWidgetを埋め込みたいということですよね?

残念ながらスマートな方法はなさそうです。
QtQuick2ではGPUでの効率的なレンダリングを実現するために、旧来のC++コードでのレンダリングは簡単には埋め込めないようです。

参考URL
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014415/qt5-embed-qwidget-object-in-qml

この質問では
* QtQuick1を使い、QGraphicsProxyWidgetを経由して表示する
* QQuickPaintedItemを使ってウィジェットをレンダリングし、イベントも仲介する。
といった解決が提示されてますね。

ちなみにアサートについては、「QWidgetは親としてQWidgetしか受け取れない」ところをそれ以外のクラスを受け取ったために発生してると思います。(setParentが仮想関数じゃないせいでちょっとわかりづらくなってる)

Answer (score 0):

`ASSERT` というのは、「ある関数を正しくない使い方したこと」を呼ばれた側の関数が自己チェックして指摘したというものです。元ソース見てませんのでアレですが

`kernel\qobject.cpp` の 1979 行を含んでいる関数をあなたのプログラムが呼ぶとき、仮引数としてポインタ引数 `d` があるわけですが、この構造体 / クラスのメンバ `isWidget` は `0` (または空ポインタ) でなければならないのに、非 `0` 値が入っているので使い方が間違っているからプログラムごと終了させちゃうよ

というのが `ASSERT` の意味合いです。

似たような質疑応答
https://forum.qt.io/topic/23090/how-to-create-a-window-using-qml
によると Qt のバージョン違いによって仕様が変わっているところなので書き直しが必要、みたいなことが書いてあります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。おかげさまで`ASSERT`の使われ方と意味については理解できました。リンクを見たところ投稿者は実装を諦めているみたいですが…どうにか実現できないものなのでしょうか？。ソースコードを追記したので、解決方法についても引き続きお知恵を貸して頂きたいです。